# Como modelar uma estrutura de dados em árvore usando um banco de dados relacional?

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, estrutura-de-dados, árvore, dados-hierárquicos

Como definir apropriadamente e eficientemente dados naturalmente organizados em árvore em bancos de dados relacionais, considerando as implicações físicas disso?  Ou seja, organizar de forma que minimize os acessos feitos em qualquer nó.

Assuma que o RDBMS não tem características especiais para lidar com isso exceto a DDL do ANSI SQL ou recursos disponíveis em todos os [principais sistemas de banco de dados relacionais](http://db-engines.com/en/ranking). Eventualmente uma otimização específica opcional pode ser útil, mas não obrigatória.

Se existir uma forma (*query*) mais adequada para acessar (varrer/atravessar) os dados estruturados desta forma, um exemplo ajudaria.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Bom, é sempre preferível utilizar um SGDB que trate dados em *árvore* de forma natural, melhor ainda quando ele for especialmente desenhado para tal fim, como por exemplo, o Neo4j.

Porém existem algumas formas de se trabalhar em  SGDB's relacionais, vou enumerar 4 delas:

### 1. Lista Adjacente

Solução mais comumente utilizada, cada entrada (registro) conhece somente seu nó superior, veja um exemplo de estrutura comumente utilizado:

#### Exemplo: Comentários em um Blog

Nesse exemplo, existe uma tabela que armazena comentários de um blog, existem os comentários principais, que não tem nós superiores (são a "raiz"), e existem os comentários que são respostas a outro comentário, e assim sucessivamente, em uma tabela do SGBD, teríamos a seguinte situação:

Tabela: `comentarios`

```
id          parent_id        usuario_id        comentario
----------------------------------------------------------------
1           NULL             33                Gostei do seu...
2           1                34                seu comentario foi exc...
3           1                99                Gostei Também...
4           3                34                Que bom que gostou...
5           NULL             80                Que Post Bacana ...
```

Renderizando, teríamos algo como:

```
Usuario 33 Comentou: Gostei do seu ...
      Usuário 34 Comentou: Seu comentario foi exc...
      Usuario 99 Comentou: Gostei Também...
            Usuário 34 Comentou: Que bom que gostou...
Usuario 80 Comentou: Que Post Bacana ...
```

Os comentários tem a mesma estrutura de dados, porem são aninhados dessa forma, é necessário percorrer recursivamente todos os dados a partir de um determinado ID.

> **Pontos POSITIVOS**: Fácil de implementar
>
> **Pontos NEGATIVOS**: Difícil de manusear em `arvores` profundas, funciona bem quando são poucos níveis

### 2. Caminho Enumerado

Basicamente a mesma estrutura do exemplo acima, porem a tabela contem o caminho desde o nó raiz até ele próprio, veja o exemplo:

Tabela `comentarios`

```
id          path_to_comment  usuario_id        comentario
----------------------------------------------------------------
1           /                33                Gostei do seu...
2           /1/2             34                seu comentario foi exc...
3           /1/3             99                Gostei Também...
4           /1/3/4           34                Que bom que gostou...
5           /                80                Que Post Bacana ...
```

dessa forma poderíamos pegar os comentários abaixo do comentário de `ID 3` fazendo algo como

```
SELECT * from comentarios WHERE path_to_comment LIKE '/1/3/%';
```

> **Pontos POSITIVOS**: Fácil de implementar, consulta mais rápida e eficiente que o método de `Lista Adjacente`
>
> **Pontos NEGATIVOS**: É relativamente difícil refazer o caminho quando realocamos um elemento

### 3. Conjuntos Aninhados

É um método um pouco mais complexo, vou dar uma visão geral, pois uma resposta completa iria prolongar muito um resposta que é um visão geral sobre os métodos, então vamos lá:

Consistem em armazenar com cada nó, dois números (um para a esquerda e outro para a direita): o da esquerda armazena um número menor que o menor ID dos seus descendentes, e o número da direita armazena um número maior, que o maior ID dos seus descendentes; então, ao fazer uma *query*, teríamos um escopo de busca que em termos de performance seria bem mais eficiente que os outros métodos, veja uma imagem que ilustra isso:

[image: Arvore de Conjuntos Aninhados]

> **Pontos POSITIVOS**: Performance muito maior, facilidade de `atravessar`.
>
> **Pontos NEGATIVOS**: Bem mais difícil para implementar do que os outros métodos; performance não é tão maior em SGDB que não tem suporte a queries recursivas (exemplo: MySQL)

**Te recomendo fazer um pergunta aqui no StackOverflow sobre essa técnica, daí eu ou outro usuário podemos te demonstrar melhorar tal técnica**

### 4. Tabela de Relacionamento

Basicamente uma tabela "Muitos-para-muitos" que armazena todas as ligações de um nó com seus descendentes, semelhante à técnica do caminho enumerado, porém um pouco mais flexível e com mais performance que tal.

> **P.S. Irei melhorar essa resposta assim que possível citando mais exemplos, mas esse é um assunto gigante, e cada uma das técnicas renderia pelo menos uma questão aqui no SO**

Comment: A dos conjuntos aninhados eu gosto muito para fazer navegação de todos os ítens com "próxima" e "anterior", basta ordenar pelo valor L para ter os ítens todos em "ordem de leitura".

Comment: A "Tabela de Relacionamento" (*closure table*) é particularmente interessante porque permite ir **além** de uma estrutura em forma de árvore - permitindo representar qualquer [Grafo Acíclico Direcionado](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grafos_ac%C3%ADclicos_dirigidos) (DAG).

Comment: @mgibsonbr vou melhorar essa resposta para incluir mais exemplos, mesmo sendo um resposta extensa, esse é um tema realmente interessante

Comment: Desculpe a falta de modéstia :) mas estou procurando perguntas interessantes. Ainda bem que tem pessoas dando respostas interessantes e surpreendentemente boas. Só vou discordar da primeira frase. Temos inúmeros motivos para usar o RDBMS para isso. Exemplos: A maior parte do sistema não precisa disso e ter 2 sistemas aumenta a complexidade; tentar um DB não relacional desconhecido porém mais adequada provavelmente resultaria em algo pior; outro DB não está disponível (binding para a linguagem ou possibilidade de uso na implantação); não realiza bem outras tarefas necessárias.

Comment: @bigown não necessáriamente está discordando da resposta, compartilho do seu pensamento, em um sistema é estramamente custoso manter mais de um banco, porém o que disse era que para tratar dados em árvore, o melhor é usar algo específico, mas não é sempre o aconselhavel

Comment: Acabei postando [uma resposta separada](http://br.stackoverflow.com/questions/2425/2486#2486). As técnicas descritas são as mesmas (afinal sua resposta está bastante completa, a princípio nem ia colocar a minha), mas organizei de uma forma diferente. Espero que seja de alguma utilidade...

Comment: @hernandev , esperando você terminar sua resposta

Answer (score 20):

Para determinar a melhor estrutura para representar sua árvore, faça as seguintes perguntas:

1. A profundidade máxima é **garantidamente muito pequena**? (i.e. no máximo uns 3)

   Se a resposta for **sim**, uma solução mais simples pode ser a ideal (as souções mais complexas "se pagam" quando a **escala** do problema é grande). A "Lista de Adjacências" (*Adjacency List*) - onde cada nó possui uma chave estrangeira para o seu pai - é uma solução simples e direta. Entretanto, [há autores](http://it-ebooks.info/book/70/) que a consideram uma "solução ingênua" (*naïve*) - aplicável sim em casos simples, mas em geral a ser evitada.

   Note que pode ser necessário escrever mais de uma query dependendo da profundidade do nó (ex.: uma pra profundidade 1, uma pra 2, uma pra 3), por isso o requisito da árvore ser garantidamente rasa. Alguns SGBDs suportam "queries recursivas" (ex.: `WITH`, `START WITH` e `CONNECT BY`) que podem simplificar a tarefa, mas não são portáveis, o que foge do escopo da pergunta.
2. A profundidade máxima prevista é **pequena**?

   Outra técnica simples, mas sem os problemas da lista de adjacências é a "Enumeração de Caminhos" (*Path Enumeration*), onde cada nó possui uma coluna texual onde está representada a lista de `id`s desde a raiz até aquele nó. É simples tanto inserir/remover/modificar nós quanto percorrê-los (seja a sub-ávore, seja seus filhos diretos), bastando uma operação no campo textual - em geral envolvendo prefixos.

   É bom notar que essa tabela estaria **desnormalizada** (não está na [primeira forma normal](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_dados)) e não possui [integridade referencial](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integridade_referencial) (a coluna aceitaria listas com `id`s inexistentes), além do quê os caminhos podem se tornar muito longos em árvores profundas. (o requisito de espaço de um nó é proporcional à sua profundidade)
3. A profundidade máxima prevista é **muito grande**? Existem nós que são ancestrais da maioria dos outros nós?

   Se a resposta for **não**, considere utilizar uma *Closure Table* (que o @hernandes chamou de "Tabela de Relacionamento", mas também poderia ser chamada "Tabela de [Fechamento](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fechamento)") - uma tabela separada onde cada linha representa uma relação `ancestral -> descendente` (e talvez `profundidade`). Essa tabela proporciona rapidez no acesso em troca de maior espaço de armazenamento, e é eficiente para praticamente todo tipo de operação.

   Uma desvantagem (se estiver usando SQL puro) é a necessidade de manter atualizadas duas tabelas, e queries relativamente complexas (porém eficientes). E se a profundidade for muito grande, os nós folha terão um número elevado de ancestrais, cada um ocupando uma linha no fechamento. (o requisito de espaço de um nó também é proporcional à profundidade, mas o overhead é maior - uma linha para cada ancestral) Uma técnica alternativa pode ser interessante, a menos que...
4. A sua árvore é modificada com frequência? Sua tabela representa mais de uma árvore? (e é factível que duas árvores venham a ser "mescladas" em algum momento?)

   Caso a resposta seja **não**, o uso de "Conjuntos Aninhados" pode oferecer uma boa performance com baixo consumo de espaço. Nele cada nó define um intervalo (dois números: limite inferior/esquerdo e limite superior/direito) e considera-se "descendente" todo nó cujo intervalo esteja contido (aninhado) no intervalo de um outro nó. Em geral, as queries de consulta são simples e eficientes, e o requisito de espaço é pequeno e fixo para cada nó (dois inteiros).

   Entretanto, embora a remoção de um nó seja barata, a inserção ou locomoção de um nó pode ser bem cara, pois é preciso atualizar **todos** os seus ancestrais, seus irmãos (da direita tradicionalmente, mas uma variação seria escolher o lado com menos irmãos) **e** os irmãos de todos os seus ancestrais (mesmo lado). Se o nó não for folha, também os seus descendentes. Se o tempo for mais importante que o espaço, é preferível adotar a *Closure Table* nessa situação.

   Nota: se a sua tabela representa **mais de uma** árvore, há uma complicação adicional: a menos que cada nó identifique a qual árvore pertence, os conjuntos de uma ávore poderiam interferir nos conjuntos da outra. Isso faria com que alterações em um nó afetasse inclusive nós de **outras árvores**! E se a mesclagem de árvores for possível, todo o conjunto de uma delas pelo menos teria de ser refeito.

---

Exemplos completos seriam muito extensos para essa resposta, mas vou incluir uma tabela comparativa das técnicas mencionadas (fonte: livro ["SQL Antipatterns"](http://it-ebooks.info/book/70/), em inglês), e somente o exemplo de código requisitado na pergunta (i.e. query para atravessar uma sub-árvore).

```
Design          Tabelas  Consultar Filho  C. Sub-Árvore  Inserção  Remoção  I. Referencial

Lista de Adj.      1          Fácil          Difícil      Fácil     Fácil      Sim
+Query Recurs.     1          Fácil           Fácil       Fácil     Fácil      Sim
Enum. Caminhos     1          Fácil           Fácil       Fácil     Fácil      Não
Conj. Aninhados    1         Difícil          Fácil      Difícil   Difícil     Não
Closure Table      2          Fácil           Fácil       Fácil     Fácil      Sim
```

- Lista de Adjacências (subárvore do nó `4`, até 3 níveis):

  ```sql
  select * from comentarios where id = 4
  union
  select * from comentarios where parent = 4
  union
  select c2.*
      from comentarios as c1 join comentarios as c2 on c2.parent = c1.id
      where c1.parent = 4;
  ```
- Enumeração de Caminhos (subárvore do nó `1/4/`):

  ```sql
  select * from comentarios as c
  where c.caminho like '1/4/' || '%';
  ```

  (Relembrando: procura por nós cujo caminho possui o prefixo `1/4/`)
- Conjuntos Aninhados (subárvore do nó `4`):

  ```sql
  select c2.*
  from comentarios as c1
  join comentarios as c2 on c2.esquerda between c1.esquerda and c1.direita
  where c1.id = 4;
  ```

  (Relembrando: procura por nós cujo intervalo - `esquerda`, e automaticamente `direita` - esteja totalmente contido no intervalo do nó)
- *Closure Table* (subárvore do nó `4`):

  ```sql
  select c.*
  from comentarios as c join closure as ad on c.id = ad.descendente
  where ad.ancestral = 4;
  ```

Answer (score 6):

Gostaria de ter colocado como comentário a resposta do @hernandes, porém, ficou um pouco extensa, então coloco aqui como resposta.

Estou usando Lista Adjacente em alguns sistemas.
Uma desvantagem é o trabalho em fazer coisas como um breadcumb. Também tem uma dificuldade em determinar quando um nó está desativado e impedir de que suas dependências sejam exibidas ou, mesmo para os ativados verificar se existem dependências relacionadas e ativas (produtos de uma loja virtual, por exemplo).

Não aconselho nenhuma dessas técnicas (adjacency, nested, etc) quando o sistema for restrito a uma profundidade pequena de até 5 nós, por exemplo. Se formos analisar bem, uma loja virtual dificilmente terá subcategorias com mais de 5 níveis de profundidade. 
Por fim, antes da escolha, é preciso entender qual o modelo de negócios.

Loja virtual? CRM? Sistema de arquivos?