# Efetuar um select a uma tabela que simula uma árvore

Tags: sql-server

Tenho uma tabela que simula uma árvore. Por exemplo:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(id int,parentId int,name varchar(max));
insert @t select 1,  0        ,'Category1'
insert @t select 2,  0,        'Category2'
insert @t select 3,  1,        'Category3'
insert @t select 4 , 2,        'Category4'
insert @t select 5 , 1,        'Category5'
insert @t select 6 , 2,        'Category6'
insert @t select 7 , 3,        'Category7'
```

O meu objetivo é pegar em cada PAI (idparent=0) e, por cada ramo que esse pai tenha listar sequencialmente todos os filhos até ao nível mais baixo. Para isso eu usei este código

```
WITH tree (id, parentid, level, name , rn) as 
(
   SELECT id, parentid, 0 as level, name,
       right(row_number() over (order by id),10) rn
   FROM @t
   WHERE parentid = 0

   UNION ALL

   SELECT c2.id, c2.parentid, tree.level + 1,  tree.name + ' - ' +c2.name,
       rn 
   FROM @t c2 
     INNER JOIN tree ON tree.id = c2.parentid
)
```

Efetuando um select à tree é-me devolvido isto:

```
id parentid level name                               rn
1  0        0     Category1                          1
2  0        0     Category2                          2
4  2        1     Category2 - Category4              2
6  2        1     Category2 - Category6              2
3  1        1     Category1 - Category3              1
5  1        1     Category1 - Category5              1
7  3        2     Category1 - Category3 - Category7  1
```

A minha dúvida surge agora como obter o que realmente quero. Deste select eu apenas preciso das linhas com os IDS 7, 6 ,4 e 6. Ou seja por cada RN eu quero sempre os níveis mais baixos. Mas não sei como obter esses valores. Alguém me sabe ajudar? (estou a usar SQL Server)

```
id parentid name                              
4  2        Category2 - Category4             
6  2        Category2 - Category6             
5  1        Category1 - Category5             
7  3        Category1 - Category3 - Category7
```

Comment: Ana, sugiro você ler [esta questão aqui do SO](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2425/como-modelar-uma-estrutura-de-dados-em-arvore-usando-um-banco-de-dados-relaciona). Lá você encontra a técnica dos "Conjuntos Aninhados" que simula uma árvore binária no banco. Essa técnica permite recuperar facilmente partes da hierarquia com queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu acredito que se você adicionar um

```
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @t c3 where c3.parentid = c2.id)
```

em

```
WITH tree (id, parentid, level, name , rn) as 
(
   SELECT id, parentid, 0 as level, name,
       right(row_number() over (order by id),10) rn
   FROM @t
   WHERE parentid = 0

   UNION ALL

   SELECT c2.id, c2.parentid, tree.level + 1,  tree.name + ' - ' +c2.name,
       rn 
   FROM @t c2 
     INNER JOIN tree ON tree.id = c2.parentid
   WHERE
     NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @t c3 where c3.parentid = c2.id)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu entendí você ques que retorne somente os que possuem níveis.
Se for isso basta adicionar `AND c2.level > 0` na consulta.

```
WITH tree (id, parentid, level, name , rn) as 
(
SELECT id, parentid, 0 as level, name,
   right(row_number() over (order by id),10) rn
FROM @t
WHERE parentid = 0

UNION ALL

SELECT c2.id, c2.parentid, tree.level + 1,  tree.name + ' - ' +c2.name,
   rn 
FROM @t c2 
   INNER JOIN tree ON tree.id = c2.parentid AND c2.level > 0
)
```

Comment: Na verdade ele que que só venha a de útlimo nível. no seu select a categoria 3 viria e ela não deve vir pois tem filhas