# Lógica de líder e liderados com recursão em Java

Tags: java, recursão

Estou com um problema relativamente simples de resolver, mas não estou conseguindo por uma deficiência lógica. Meu problema é o seguinte:

Possuo uma hierarquia de lideres e liderados. Por exemplo:

```
Lider 1
    Lider 1.1
        Lider 1.1.1
        Lider 1.1.2
        Lider 1.1.3
            Lider 1.1.3.1
    Lider 1.2
        Lider 1.2.1
    Lider 1.3
```

E assim vai. Quantos níveis forem necessários. No banco de dados, isso já está mapeado. Ou seja, eu consigo saber quem é líder de quem usando a seguinte query de exemplo:

```
select * from colaboradores where lider_id = ?;
```

No entanto, não estou conseguindo montar uma recursão eficiente em Java para retornar todos os líderes abaixo. Por exemplo, se eu passar para o meu método o ID do líder 1.1, deveria retorna para mim uma lista assim:

```
Lider 1.1
Lider 1.1.1
Lider 1.1.2
Lider 1.1.3
Lider 1.1.3.1
```

Alguém tem uma luz para mim aí?

**ATUALIZAÇÃO:**
Tentei fazer via mapeamento do próprio JPA. Só uma nota: O relacionamento entre líderes e liderados não é feito via ID da classe, e sim um outro campo que não é chave estrangeiro. Esse outro campo é a matrícula. Vejam:

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Colaborador.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "matricula_lider", referencedColumnName = "matricula", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Colaborador lider;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="lider", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Colaborador> liderados;
```

Bom, se eu usar só o mapeamento:

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Colaborador.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "matricula_lider", referencedColumnName = "matricula", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Colaboradorlider;
```

Funciona legal e eu consigo obter o líder da pessoa. Se eu usar ambos mapeamentos (bi-direcional), da erro ao tentar recuperar. Na verdade não dá erro, parece que entra em loop infinito até dar timeout da transação.

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Transaction was rolled back in a different thread!
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
```

...

Meu mapeamento está errado?

Comment: Sugestão de leitura altamente relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2425/como-modelar-uma-estrutura-de-dados-em-%C3%A1rvore-usando-um-banco-de-dados-relaciona

Comment: Sugestões de implementação irão depender do seu modelo lógico. Um grupo pode possuir mais de um líder? Um líder pode ser um colaborador de outro grupo? Um líder pode ser líder de vários grupos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considerando que sua hierarquia no banco de dados é mapeada usando-se uma chave estrangeira que aponta para a própria classe,

Você pode fazer o mesmo conceito no java:

```
class Pessoa {
   Pessoa lider;
   List<Pessoa> colaboradores;
}
```

Uma pessoa é lider se possuir colaboradores, e o lider de uma pessoa é um outra pessoa. Isso é recursivo, mas você vai ter um desafio que é Transformar de Objeto para Relacional e Vice-versa.

Se usar hibernate ele irá cuidar desse problema:

```
@Entity
class Pessoa {
@ManyToOne
Pessoa lider;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="lider", fetch=FetchType.LAZY )
List<Pessoa> colaboradores;
}
```

E então usando uma JQL

```
EntityManager em;
// Obtem o entitymanager conforme o padrão usado, JTA ou RESOURCE_LOCAL
em.createQuery("select p from Pessoa p where p.lider = :lider_id").setParam("lider_id", 2).getResultList(); // Retorna uma lista de Pessoas
```

Comment: Atualizei minha pergunta com o mapeamento que tentei usar para corrigir o problema. Mas deu um erro. Você consegue analisar o motivo? Meu mapeamento está errado?

Comment: @RicardoGiaviti Vai dar loop infinito porque vc usa ```FetchType.EAGER``` em ambos os lados como é recursivo o hibernate pode carregar toda sua base de colaboradores na memória desse jeito! Você vai ter que usar o relacionamento Lazy pelo ao menos no @OneToMany da lista de colaboradores

Comment: Na verdade deu loope infinito porque o Líder 1 era Líder dele mesmo. Aí não tinha jeito. Fui ver isso depois de bater cabeça muito tempo.

Answer (score 3):

Existem diferentes técnicas para modelar uma estrutura hierárquica num banco de dados relacional, como pode ser visto na questão:

> ***[Como modelar uma estrutura de dados em árvore usando um banco de dados relacional?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2425/227)***

A solução mais direta, porém sofrível em questão de desempenho é usar um critério com `like`. Exemplo:

```sql
select * from colaboradores where lider_id like ? || '%'; -- oracle
select * from colaboradores where lider_id like ? + '%'; -- sql server
```

Nota: considera-se que o campo `lider_id` seja um `VARCHAR` ou `VARCHAR2`.

Essa solução só não fica tão ruim se houver um índice criado para o campo `lider_id`, garantindo que o SGBDR não precise ler a tabela toda (*table scan*).

Índices em colunas de texto funcionam até um certo número de caracteres e se não usar a '%' no começo, mas somente no final do critério de pesquisa.