# Como preencher os dados de uma elemento em formato de árvore?

Tags: algoritmo

Eu tenho um elemento `p:tree` do Primefaces, e gostaria de preencher ele com dados existentes num `ArrayList`.

Na verdade eu gostaria apenas de ter uma ideia sobre como poderia ser o algorítimo que fizesse isto.

**Objectivo:**

A ideia é representar os dados da "Lista de dados" em um elemento com a estrutura de árvore, especificamente o `p:tree` (creio que a imagem expressa melhor a ideia):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qualquer ideia é bem vinda, não precisa ser necessariamente uma resposta especifica em relação à plataforma, apenas um algorítimo serviria.

Comment: Questão estreitamente relacionada, mas não igual (no meu ponto de vista): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2425/como-modelar-uma-estrutura-de-dados-em-%C3%A1rvore-usando-um-banco-de-dados-relaciona

Comment: O que exatamente está te trazendo dificuldades? Supondo que dado um nó você consiga acrescentar filhos nele (não conheço Primefaces, mas [esse exemplo](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/tree/basic.xhtml#j_idt98:j_idt101) sugere que sim), minha sugestão é para cada item do `ArrayList` você acrescenta uma entrada em um `HashMap<Integer,TreeNode>` associando o `ID` do dado com o nó que você criou pra ele; então você pega o nó superior desse mesmo dado, consulta no mesmo map para obter o nó pai, e então acrescenta o filho no pai (ou no root, se não há pai). É +- isso, ou outra coisa?

Comment: É + ou - isso mesmo.Obrigado pela ideia.

Answer (score 1):

Só para não ficar sem resposta, resolvi implementar o algoritmo em JavaScript.

Os comentários explicam melhor do que um parágrafo introdutório, mas observo aqui que este código pode ser facilmente adaptado para qualquer linguagem, principalmente as orientadas a objeto. Evitei declarações de classe e complicações desnecessárias, mas incluí uma função para impressão do resultado, apenas para a comodidade de quem quiser testar o código (basta clicar em **Executar trecho de código**).

Reparem que esta solução se baseia no fato de que os nós são descritos, no array de dados (`dados`), na sequência crescente de seus códigos (ID's).

O algoritmo, entretanto, **pode ser facilmente adaptado** para suportar sequências arbitrárias de descrição, desde que o código seja informado na 3ª coluna do array, por exemplo; basta incluir o código como um valor secundário (`id: dados[i][2]`, neste novo exemplo), dentro da estrutura de cada nó (1º loop do algoritmo), e então realizar a comparação (`if`, no 2º loop) a partir deste código armazenado, ao invés de usar o índice do loop (`i+1`).

```js
// Array de dados. A primeira coluna é o valor do nó; a segunda, indica o nó pai.
var dados = [
    [ "Dado 1", null ],
    [ "Dado 2", 1    ],
    [ "Dado 3", 1    ],
    [ "Dado 4", 2    ],
    [ "Dado 5", 2    ],
    [ "Dado 6", 4    ],
    [ "Dado 7", 5    ]
];

// Declaração do array que conterá cada nó:
var nos = [];

// Transformação de cada elemento do array de dados em um nó (ainda sem relacionamento):
for(var i = 0; i < dados.length; i++){
    nos.push({
        valor: dados[i][0],
        filhos: []
    });
}

/*
  CRIAÇÃO DOS RELACIONAMENTOS:
  A ideia é que cada nó procure por seus filhos no array de dados; como o índice de um
  elemento no array de dados é exatamente o mesmo índice do seu respectivo nó, no array
  de nós, basta que cada nó procure no array de dados quais deles fizeram referência a ele:
*/
for(var i = 0; i < nos.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < dados.length; j++){
        if(i+1 == dados[j][1]) nos[i].filhos.push(nos[j]); // i+1 porque os índices começam em 0.
    }
}

// Imprime o resultado:
print(nos[0], "&rarr; "); // nos[0] representa o nó raiz da árvore.


//==============================================================================================


/*
  EXTRA:
  Função recursiva para imprimir a árvore (com busca em profundidade), apenas para visualizar
  o resultado.
  Varia bastante de linguagem para linguagem, no JavaScript está é uma das formas de fazer:
*/
function print(no, recuo){
    var p = document.createElement("p"); // Cria um parágrafo HTML.
    p.innerHTML = recuo + no.valor;      // Seta o texto deste parágrafo para indentação + valor.
    document.body.appendChild(p);        // Joga o parágrafo na tela (torna visível).
    // Se possuir filhos...
    if(no.filhos.length > 0) for(var i = 0; i < no.filhos.length; i++){
        // ...imprime cada um deles, com um recuo 8 espaços maior:
        print(no.filhos[i], "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + recuo);
    }
}
```