# Persistir "pedaços" de uma árvore (grande) em paralelo

Tags: algoritmo, paralelismo, árvore

Me encontro com o seguinte problema em mãos:

**Objetivo:** Paralelizar um processo ETL que:

- Lê de uma interface externa uma árvore com um número indeterminado de elementos.
- Transforma a representação
- Escreve esses valores em um banco de dados local.

#### A implementação atual

Começa lendo todos os dados da interface externa para uma estrutura em memória:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> arvore = leArvore("v=raiz");
```

A chave do mapa é um caminho para determinado elemento da árvore. O valor do mapa por sua vez é um segundo mapa ligando nomes de atributos aos seus respectivos valores:

Exemplo:

```
{ 
    'v=raiz' = {
        'nome_atributo_1' : 'valor_1', 
        'nome_atributo_2' : 'valor_2' 
    }, 
    'v=raiz,v=elemento_1' = {
        'nome_atributo_3' : 'valor_3' 
    },
    'v=raiz,v=elemento_2' = {
        'nome_atributo_4' : 'valor_4' 
    }, 
    'v=raiz,v=elemento_1,v=elemento_3' = {
        'nome_atributo_5' : 'valor_5',
        'nome_atributo_6' : 'valor_6',
        'nome_atributo_7' : 'valor_7'   
    } 
}
```

Essa estrutura sofre então um processo de tradução (mapeando os valores dos atributos para tipos conhecidos).

Finalmente um algoritmo recursivo escreve a árvore no banco de dados:

```
void escreveArvore(String caminhoNo) {
    // Persiste o elemento e seus atributos
    persisteElemento(caminhoNo, arvore.get(caminhoNo));
    arvore.remove(caminhoNo);
    for (String caminhoFilho : filhosDiretos(caminhoNo)) {
        escreveArvore(caminhoFilho);    
    }
} 

escrevaArvore("v=raiz");
```

#### Por que estamos mudando a implementação?

Essas árvores podem ser gigantescas e profundas. 
O nosso *flow* carrega várias dessas árvores em memória, o que volta e meia resulta em `OutOfMemoryError`s. Além disso, a interface externa responde bem melhor a pequenas consultas que retornam um bloco de elementos do que uma consulta que retorna a árvore inteira.

#### Leitura e transformação em blocos:

```
int tamanhoBloco = 100;
int quantidadeFilhos = contaFilhos("v=raiz");
int quantidadeBlocos  = quantidadeFilhos / tamanhoBloco + 1;
// Esse laço é mais rápido do que leArvore("v=raiz"), mesmo sem paralelismo
for (int bloco = 0; i < quantidadeBlocos  ; bloco++) {
    Map<String, Map<String, Object>> blocoAtual = leFilhos("raiz", bloco, tamanhoBloco);
}
```

Essa parte pode ser facilmente paralelizada criando um *pool* de *threads* e submetendo cada bloco para um `ExecutorService`.

A transformação também pode ser facilmente reescrita com lógica similar. Uma `ArrayBlockingQueue` pode ser utilizado como *broker* entre o leitor e transformador. O transformador pode receber e processar cada bloco tão cedo o leitor termine o seu trabalho.

## O problema

Não tenho ideia do como paralelizar a escrita da árvore do banco de dados.

Eu não posso simplesmente persistir uma bloco por vez pois tenho que ter persistido **todos os parentes** de determinado elemento **antes de persistir o elemento** em questão. Exemplo, no grafo acima só posso persistir `elemento_3` depois de ter persistido `raiz` e `elemento_1`.

Operações de escrita no banco também são bastante custosas e os tempos acumulam facilmente.

Minha primeira tentativa foi utilizar uma estrutura auxiliar:

```
// Caminho do elemento ligado à uma flag dizendo se esse já foi persistido
Map<String, Boolean> elementosPersistidos = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, boolean>();
```

Nesse versão eu substituí o algoritmo recursivo por uma lógica que tenta persistir cada bloco de elementos em paralelo. Ao encontrar um caminho com parentes não persistidos eu insiro parentes *dummy* no banco de dados (que são posteriormente substituídos pelos elementos verdadeiros). A performance ficou abismal devido à maior quantidade de *writes*.

Por outro lado manter o método recursivo significa que eventualmente a árvore inteira acaba em memória. Com as leituras mais rápidas a escrita se torna o gargalo e as chances de `OutOfMemory` aumentam.

Existe algum algoritmo conhecido para escrever "pedaços" de uma árvore em paralelo? Dentre esses algoritmos, existe algum que se adapte bem à minha situação, i.e., em que elementos da árvore cheguem desordenadamente em blocos, e é desejável simultaneamente minimizar o uso de memória e a quantidade de escritas?

---

### *Updates*

#### Métodos que usam a interface externa

```
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> leArvore(String raiz);
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> leFilhos(String no, int bloco, int tamanhoBloco);
```

O único método que usa o banco é:

```
void persisteElemento(String caminhoNo, Map<String, Object> atributos);
```

#### Exemplo de escrita fora de ordem

```
Bloco 1:
    v=raiz
    v=raiz,v=elemento_1
Bloco 2: 
    v=raiz,v=elemento_1,v=elemento_3
```

Se `Bloco 2` for lido / processado antes do `Bloco 1`, o próximo passo seria chamar`persisteElemento` para `elemento_3`, nessa situação estaríamos tentando persistir `elemento_3` antes de `raiz` e `elemento_1` (o que estamos tentando evitar).

---

P.S: A linguagem em questão é Java e o banco é Versant, porém no momento estou mais preocupado com o algoritmo em si do que com a implementação. Como eu não quis restringir a pergunta, respostas em pseudo-código são bem vindas.

Comment: Olha, a dica que vou te dar não tem relação com a sua dúvida, mas é algo que um amigo fez em um problema de doutorado e ele me disse que a velocidade que ele conseguiu é ordens de magnitude maior. O que ele fez foi usar um ramdisk (um drive que é mapeado para a memória RAM, valido no Linux). Se você tiver memória RAM suficiente, você pode rodar o seu algoritmo em um banco intermediário que está todo na RAM. Ao final, você grava os dados no banco oficial. Obviamente, você precisa ter RAM suficiente, Ele tem 64 GB e gastou 40 GB. Basicamente, colocou um SQLite todo na memoria RAM.

Comment: Obviamente, meu comentário acima só ajuda na parte de persistir no banco, já que a velocidade dessa parte vai aumentar. Isso não ajuda no OutOfMemoryException que acontece ao processar a árvore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Desafio de paralelismo

A primeira coisa que se deve ter em mente quando se pensa em paralelismo é a dependência de cada tarefa que potencialmente pode ser executada em paralelo.

Claro que nem tudo é preto no branco quando falamos de paralelismo e concorrência, mas neste caso em específico creio que isso faz uma diferença crucial, já que a dependência do nó pai para persistir um nó filho é grande parte do problema.

A técnica de gravar um registro *dummy* foi bem interessante, mas não resolve o problema porque tecnicamente prolonga o tempo da tarefa enquanto a dependência não é satisfeita. Poderia funcionar em outros cenários, entretanto, talvez onde o custo de acesso ao banco fosse menor que o de processamento.

## Possível solução: Produtor x Consumidor

Divagações teóricas a parte, um método que consegui pensar para satisfazer as dependências e manter um grau razoável de paralelização consiste numa aplicação específica do padrão Produtor x Consumidor.

Nessa implementação, o mesmo componente exerce o papel de consumidor e produtor:

- Primeiro ele consome um dado elemento `E` da fila.
- Processa `E`, no caso, inserindo-o no banco de dados, obtendo seu ID e assim resolvendo as dependências de seus filhos.
- Finalmente, o componente exerce o papel de produtor e coloca os filhos de `E` na fila para serem processados em paralelo.

Isso significa que a raiz da árvore será processada sem paralelismo, mas a partir daí todos os filhos podem ser potencialmente processados em paralelo, assim como os filhos dos filhos até que praticamente todos os elementos "folha" da árvore podem ser paralelizados.

Um detalha interessante é que, no papel de consumidor, esta implementação somente precisa conhecer a árvore parcialmente, isto é, o nó sendo processado. Enquanto que o produtor precisa apenas conhecer os seus filhos. Realmente não ser o impacto disso numa execução em grande escala, mas em teoria não é precisa armazenar em memória o que não está sendo processado.

## Implementação de exemplo

Fiz uma implementação básica de exemplo usando as informações disponíveis e acredito que seja possível adaptá-lo conforme as necessidades do projeto.

Veja abaixo:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class TreeConsumerExample {

    //cria mapa de atributos a partir dos parâmetros: chave, valor, chave, valor...
    Map<String, Object> mapOf(Object... args) {
        Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i += 2) {
            m.put((String) args[i], args[i+1]);
        }
        return m;
    }

    final Map<String, Map<String, Object>> arvore = new HashMap<>();
    final ArrayBlockingQueue<ElementoArvore> fila = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(64);
    final AtomicLong ultimoIdInseridoNoBanco = new AtomicLong();
    final AtomicLong quantidadeElementosProcessados = new AtomicLong();

    //inicia arvore
    TreeConsumerExample() {
        arvore.put("v=raiz", mapOf("nome_atributo_1", "valor_1", "nome_atributo_2", "valor_2"));
        arvore.put("v=raiz,v=elemento_1", mapOf("nome_atributo_3", "valor_3"));
        arvore.put("v=raiz,v=elemento_2", mapOf("nome_atributo_4", "valor_4"));
        arvore.put("v=raiz,v=elemento_1,v=elemento_3", mapOf("nome_atributo_5", "valor_5", "nome_atributo_6", "valor_6", "nome_atributo_7", "valor_7"));
    }

    //armazena informacoes de um elemento da árvore na fila
    static class ElementoArvore {
        final String caminhoNo;
        final Map<String, Object> valores;
        final Long idPai;
        public ElementoArvore(String caminhoNo, Map<String, Object> valores, Long idPai) {
            this.caminhoNo = caminhoNo;
            this.valores = valores;
            this.idPai = idPai;
        }
        public Map<String, Object> getValores() {
            return valores;
        }
        public Long getIdPai() {
            return idPai;
        }
        public String getCaminhoNo() {
            return caminhoNo;
        }
    }

    //persiste um elemento e retorna o novo ID
    Long persisteElemento(ElementoArvore elemento) {
        Long novoId = ultimoIdInseridoNoBanco.incrementAndGet();
        System.out.printf("Persistindo %s | valores = %s | id pai = %d, novo id = %d%n", elemento.getCaminhoNo(),
                elemento.getValores(), elemento.getIdPai(), novoId);
        return novoId;
    }

    //recupera os filhos de um elemento a partir do caminho
    Collection<String> filhosDiretos(String caminhoNo) {
        return arvore.keySet().stream()
                .filter(k -> k.length() > caminhoNo.length() && k.startsWith(caminhoNo) && k.substring(caminhoNo.length() + 1).indexOf(',')  < 0)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    //thread que retira um elemento da fila, processa e adiciona os filhos
    class ConsumidorProdutor extends Thread {
        final Integer threadNumber;

        public ConsumidorProdutor(Integer threadNumber) {
            this.threadNumber = threadNumber;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    //recupera elemento da fila para processar
                    final ElementoArvore e = fila.take();

                    //verifica poison object
                    if (e.getCaminhoNo() == null) {
                        //se null, fim da fila, recoloca o elemento para acordar outras threads e finaliza a thread atual
                        fila.put(e);
                        System.out.printf("Fim da fila sinalizado. Finalizando thread %d%n", threadNumber);
                        break;
                    }

                    //procesa elemento
                    System.out.printf("Processando elemento %s na thread %d%n", e.getCaminhoNo(), threadNumber);
                    final Long novoId = persisteElemento(e);

                    //insere filhos para processamento usando o ID inserido
                    for (String caminhoFilho : filhosDiretos(e.getCaminhoNo())) {
                        fila.put(new ElementoArvore(caminhoFilho, arvore.get(caminhoFilho), novoId));
                    }

                    //verifica final do processamento
                    if (quantidadeElementosProcessados.incrementAndGet() >= arvore.size()) {
                        //elemento demarcando fim do processamento
                        //isso faz com que as threads sejam "acordadas" e terminem
                        fila.put(new ElementoArvore(null, null, null));
                        System.out.printf("Fim da fila encontrado. Finalizando thread %d%n", threadNumber);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    void escreveArvore(String caminhoNo) {
        //cria pool de threads
        final ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            threadPool.execute(new ConsumidorProdutor(i+1));
        }

        //coloca o elemento raiz na fila para iniciar o processamento
        try {
            fila.put(new ElementoArvore(caminhoNo, arvore.get(caminhoNo), null));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        //aguarda término
        threadPool.shutdown();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TreeConsumerExample().escreveArvore("v=raiz");
    }
}
```

Para detectar o final do processamento, verifico o contador de itens processados com o tamanho árvore. Isso deve ser melhorado, principalmente porque só funciona se toda a árvore for percorrida.

Além disso, a implementação usa um objeto "envenenado" para demarcar o final da execução. Isso é necessário porque as várias threads estarão bloqueadas aguardando novos elementos na fila. Então, objetos sem valor são colocados para que as threads sejam "acordadas" e então elas verificam que na verdade receberam um objeto vazio, finalizando então a execução.

Outro detalhe de implementação é que o `ArrayBlockingQueue` não irá permitir mais elementos do que a capacidade informada no construtor. Isso significa que um produtor poderá ser bloqueado ao tentar inserir um elemento na fila se ela estiver cheia até que um consumidor retire elementos da fila. A vantagem é que o uso de memória vai permanecer relativamente constante durante toda a execução.

Porém, dependendo do balanceamento da árvore, pode ser que muitos nós sejam inseridos e poucos retirados e a execução acabe num *dead lock*. Se esse for o caso, substituir por `LinkedBlockingDeque` resolve a questão, embora haja maior uso de memória.

### Versão com `LinkedBlockingDeque`

```
public class TreeConsumerExample {

    //cria mapa de atributos a partir dos parâmetros: chave, valor, chave, valor...
    Map<String, Object> mapOf(Object... args) {
        Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i += 2) {
            m.put((String) args[i], args[i+1]);
        }
        return m;
    }

    final Map<String, Map<String, Object>> arvore = new HashMap<>();
    final LinkedBlockingDeque<ElementoArvore> fila = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();
    final AtomicLong ultimoIdInseridoNoBanco = new AtomicLong();
    final AtomicLong quantidadeElementosProcessados = new AtomicLong();

    //inicia arvore
    TreeConsumerExample() {
        arvore.put("v=raiz", mapOf("nome_atributo_1", "valor_1", "nome_atributo_2", "valor_2"));
        arvore.put("v=raiz,v=elemento_1", mapOf("nome_atributo_3", "valor_3"));
        arvore.put("v=raiz,v=elemento_2", mapOf("nome_atributo_4", "valor_4"));
        arvore.put("v=raiz,v=elemento_1,v=elemento_3", mapOf("nome_atributo_5", "valor_5", "nome_atributo_6", "valor_6", "nome_atributo_7", "valor_7"));
    }

    //armazena informacoes de um elemento da árvore na fila
    static class ElementoArvore {
        final String caminhoNo;
        final Map<String, Object> valores;
        final Long idPai;
        public ElementoArvore(String caminhoNo, Map<String, Object> valores, Long idPai) {
            this.caminhoNo = caminhoNo;
            this.valores = valores;
            this.idPai = idPai;
        }
        public Map<String, Object> getValores() {
            return valores;
        }
        public Long getIdPai() {
            return idPai;
        }
        public String getCaminhoNo() {
            return caminhoNo;
        }
    }

    //persiste um elemento e retorna o novo ID
    Long persisteElemento(ElementoArvore elemento) {
        Long novoId = ultimoIdInseridoNoBanco.incrementAndGet();
        System.out.printf("Persistindo %s | valores = %s | id pai = %d, novo id = %d%n", elemento.getCaminhoNo(),
                elemento.getValores(), elemento.getIdPai(), novoId);
        return novoId;
    }

    //recupera os filhos de um elemento a partir do caminho
    Collection<String> filhosDiretos(String caminhoNo) {
        return arvore.keySet().stream()
                .filter(k -> k.length() > caminhoNo.length() && k.startsWith(caminhoNo) && k.substring(caminhoNo.length() + 1).indexOf(',')  < 0)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    //thread que retira um elemento da fila, processa e adiciona os filhos
    class ConsumidorProdutor extends Thread {
        final Integer threadNumber;

        public ConsumidorProdutor(Integer threadNumber) {
            this.threadNumber = threadNumber;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    //recupera elemento da fila para processar
                    final ElementoArvore e = fila.take();

                    //verifica poison object
                    if (e.getCaminhoNo() == null) {
                        //se null, fim da fila, recoloca o elemento para acordar outras threads e finaliza a thread atual
                        fila.add(e);
                        System.out.printf("Fim da fila sinalizado. Finalizando thread %d%n", threadNumber);
                        break;
                    }

                    //procesa elemento
                    System.out.printf("Processando elemento %s na thread %d%n", e.getCaminhoNo(), threadNumber);
                    final Long novoId = persisteElemento(e);

                    //insere filhos para processamento usando o ID inserido
                    fila.addAll(filhosDiretos(e.getCaminhoNo()).stream()
                            .map(caminhoFilho -> new ElementoArvore(caminhoFilho, arvore.get(caminhoFilho), novoId))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList()));

                    //verifica final do processamento
                    if (quantidadeElementosProcessados.incrementAndGet() >= arvore.size()) {
                        //elemento demarcando fim do processamento
                        //isso faz com que as threads sejam "acordadas" e terminem
                        fila.add(new ElementoArvore(null, null, null));
                        System.out.printf("Fim da fila encontrado. Finalizando thread %d%n", threadNumber);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    void escreveArvore(String caminhoNo) {
        //cria pool de threads
        final ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            threadPool.execute(new ConsumidorProdutor(i+1));
        }

        //coloca o elemento raiz na fila para iniciar o processamento
        try {
            fila.put(new ElementoArvore(caminhoNo, arvore.get(caminhoNo), null));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        //aguarda término
            threadPool.shutdown();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TreeConsumerExample().escreveArvore("v=raiz");
    }
}
```

### Considerações

Esta solução depende de ser possível a leitura rápida dos filhos diretos de um nó, de forma que não seja possível um filho ser encontrado antes do pai.

O quanto esta implementação pode gerar de ganho (se não acabar piorando) não é possível dizer.

O que posso teorizar é que o ganho será proporcional ao número de filhos que os nós costumam ter numa árvore. Se os nós tiverem, em média, menos de dois nós, a execução será praticamente serial. Embora sem o overhead de uma pilha muito grande de execução, ainda assim haverá tempo gasto sincronizando a fila.

## Outra possível solução: alteração na estrutura dos dados de leitura

Na verdade, um conjunto de soluções pode emergir se for possível alterar a modelagem de leitura. Isso lembra vagamente uma [antiga pergunta sobre modelagem de árvores em bancos de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2425/como-modelar-uma-estrutura-de-dados-em-%C3%A1rvore-usando-um-banco-de-dados-relaciona), mas num sentido diferente.

Neste cenário, cada nó teria um campo com a profundidade `p` de forma que a leitura da árvore pudesse ser feita ordenada pelo nível ([*level-order*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Breadth-first)), onde `p('v=raiz')=1`, `p('v=raiz,v=elemento_1')=2` e assim por diante. A quantidade de vírgulas (mais um) seria igual á profundidade.

Umas das possibilidades de algoritmo é a que se segue.

Sejam:

- `p` a profundidade de um nó na árvore
- `n` um nó
- `q` quantidade de nós em um nível `p`
- `b` um bloco de nós em um nível `p`, com divisão igual a partir da quantidade `q`
- `l(p,b)` a lista de nós de um bloco `b`, numa profundidade `p`
- `k` a chave de um nó
- `m(p,n)=k`: um mapa que armazena uma chave `k` data uma profundidade `p` e um nó `n`
- `n.p` um nó pai do nó atual

Um algoritmo poderia ser:

1. Faça `p=1` (raiz)
2. Contar nós `n` onde `p(n)=1`, finalizar se `q=0`
3. Dividir quantidade `q` de nós em blocos e, para cada bloco `b`, processar em paralelo da seguinte forma:

   1. Obter lista `l(p,b)`, cujos nós sejam de profundidade `p` e pertencentes ao bloco `b`
   2. Processar cada nó `n` na lista:
   3. Recuperar chave do pai acessando `m(p-1,n.p)`, se não houver é porque é raiz
   4. Gravar no banco de dados
   5. Recuperar chave primária `k`
   6. Salvar chave fazendo `m(p,n)=k`
4. Aguardar o processamento paralelos dos blocos
5. Remover nós pais do mapa, `m(p-1,*)`, pois não serão mais necessários
6. Incrementar profundidade `p++`
7. Voltar ao passo 2

A ideia básica é processar os níveis da árvore em sequência, já que cada nível depende do anterior, porém paralelizando o processamento dos nós de cada nível.

Os níveis já processados podem ser descartados, exceto o último (`p-1`) que contém a informação dos pais do nível atual.

Para que seja possível obter os nós por nível, o método na interface teri que ser algo assim:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> leNos(int nivelProfundidade, int bloco, int tamanhoBloco);
```

### Considerações

O algoritmo acima é bem mais complexo e só funciona bem se houverem bastante nós por nível da árvore.

Ele só funciona se for possível alterar a interface e a estrutura de leitura.

Seria possível modificar e otimizar o algoritmo ainda dependendo de que tipos de modificação fossem possíveis no banco de dados.

## Mais uma possível solução: relacionamento pré-determinado

A ideia básica é conseguir referenciar um nó no banco de dados de destino sem que seja necessário ter o registro dados no banco de dados.

Esta me parece a solução mais simples do ponto de vista de um algoritmo, embora a viabilidade dependa de alguns fatores.

Imagino que na implementação atual, cada nó tenha uma chave estrangeira para o pai, cujo valor é a chave primária do mesmo, que por sua vez é gerada ao inserir o registro.

Por outro lado, se alterássemos a estrutura do banco de modo que a chave-estrangeira do registro fosse algo como o caminho do nó no mapa (ou talvez um hash dele), poderíamos então inserir um filho antes do pai pois a chave-estrangeira seria facilmente determinada de forma independente.

Claro que restrições como integridade referencial de chaves-estrangeiras precisam estar relaxadas para não obrigar a existência do registro referenciado.

O método `persisteElemento` iria gravar essa informação derivada do `caminhoNo`, por exemplo:

- Para a raiz `'v=raiz'`, o valor do nó pai seria `null` e o identificador do nó seria o caminho `'v=raiz'`.
- Para o elemento `'v=raiz,v=elemento_1'`, o valor do nó pai seria `v=raiz`, ou seja, o caminho deste nó menos o que tem da última vírgula adiante. O identificador deste nó seria `'v=raiz,v=elemento_1'`.
- Todos os filhos do nó `'v=raiz,v=elemento_1'` teriam como nó pai o valor `'v=raiz,v=elemento_1'`.

Como já mencionei, os valores acima podem ser substituídos, talvez, pelo *hash code* para economizar espaço, pois ocupar mais espaço é um dos maiores impactos, senão o maior, desta abordagem.

## Uma última possível solução: lista de espera

Outra abordagem seria usar uma lista de espera para deixar os nós temporariamente órfaos.

Bem, na verdade, não apenas uma única lista, mas uma lista por nó pai que está ausente.

Sempre que um nó não tiver o pai, ele será adicionado à lista de espera relacionada ao pai.

Quando um nó qualquer for inserido no banco, verifica-se então se existe uma lista de espera para ele. Se existir, os nós em espera são adicionados novamente na lista de processamento ou processados imediatamente, conforme for desejado.

Uma implementação simplificado seria:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

public class WaitProducerExample {

    //exemplo de sequência de leitura
    final List<String> leituraFake = Arrays.asList("v=raiz,v=elemento_1,v=elemento_3", "v=raiz", "v=raiz,v=elemento_1");

    //fila de processamento
    final LinkedBlockingDeque<String> fila = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();

    //lista de nós pendentes, key -> nó pai, value -> nós aguardando leitura
    final ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<String>> listaDeEspera = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    //chaves dos nós inseridos
    final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Long> inseridos = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    //sequência de ids fake
    final AtomicLong ultimoIdInseridoNoBanco = new AtomicLong();

    //persiste um elemento e retorna o novo ID
    Long persisteElemento(String caminhoNo, Long idPai) {
        final Long novoId = ultimoIdInseridoNoBanco.incrementAndGet();
        System.out.printf("Persistindo %s | id pai = %d | novo id = %d%n", caminhoNo, idPai, novoId);
        return novoId;
    }

    //recupera o caminho do pai, dado o caminho do filho
    String getPai(String caminhoNo) {
        final int v = caminhoNo.lastIndexOf(',');
        return v > 0 ? caminhoNo.substring(0, v) : "";
    }

    void escreveArvore() {
        //faz uma leitura fake de um bloco desordenado de nós
        fila.addAll(leituraFake);

        //percorre fila até acabarem os elementos
        while (!fila.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                //caminho do nó
                final String no = fila.take();
                //caminho do pai
                final String pai = getPai(no);

                System.out.printf("Processando nó %s, pai = %s%n", no, pai);

                //verifica se o pai já foi inserido
                //sincronizações separadas são necessárias porque em uma thread o caminho do nó pai é usado para guardar
                //o nó atual na lista de espera, enquanto em outra thread o nó atual funciona como pai, consomindo a lista de espera
                final Long idPai = inseridos.get(pai);
                if (pai.isEmpty() || idPai != null) {
                    //se for raiz (caminho do pai vazio) ou se o pai foi encontrado, persiste o elemento e salva o ID inserido
                    inseridos.put(no, persisteElemento(no, idPai));
                    //sincroniza o nó para evitar que outra thread possa adicionar elementos na espera enquanto estiver consumindo
                    synchronized (no) {
                        //verifica se tinha alguém esperando
                        List<String> filhosEsperando = listaDeEspera.remove(no);
                        if (filhosEsperando == null) {
                            System.out.printf("Nenhum filho aguardando...%n");
                        } else {
                            //coloca de volta na fila principal (poderia processar imediatamente, mas acabaria em um algoritmo recursivo)
                            System.out.printf("Encontrado(s) %d filho(s) aguardando que já podem voltar para a fila: %s%n", filhosEsperando.size(), filhosEsperando);
                            fila.addAll(filhosEsperando);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    //senão coloca o nó na lista de espera associada com o caminho do pai
                    //sincroniza no pai para evitar que elementos sejam adicionados na lista de espera enquanto ela está sendo consumida
                    //se o pai for adicionado em algum momento após a verificação, o elemento estaria pronto para ser inserido, portanto deve voltar para a fila
                    synchronized (pai) {
                        //verifica novamente se não foi inserido, pois em caso de concorrência o estado pode mudar de uma linha para outra
                        if (inseridos.get(pai) == null) {
                            System.out.printf("Pai não encontrado, aguardando na lista de espera...%n");
                            listaDeEspera.compute(pai, (k, v) -> {
                                if (v == null) v = new ArrayList<>();
                                v.add(no);
                                return v;
                            });
                        } else {
                            //caso o pai tenha sido inserido entre a verificação acima e o bloco sincronizado, recoloca na fila normal ao invés da lista de espera
                            fila.add(no);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        //verifica se nada ficou esquecida na espera
        if (!listaDeEspera.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.printf("Ops... você esqueceu de alguma coisa, não?!%n");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new WaitProducerExample().escreveArvore();
    }
}
```

### Observações

A implementação acima não usa threads, mas simula a inserção dos nós com filho primeiro que o pai.

Mesmo não usando threads, coloquei controle de sincronização que *deve* dar conta de problemas de concorrência, como no caso de adicionar e remover itens da lista de espera ao mesmo tempo. Isso ocorre porque uma thread pode encontrar um nó órfão e tentar inserir na lista de espera enquanto outra thread pode encontrar o pai e tentar drenar os elementos da lista. O objeto a ser sincronizado deve ser o pai no primeiro caso e o próprio nó no segundo, pois no primeiro estamos usando o pai ausente como referência e no segundo o nó encontrado seria o pai do nó órfão. Complicado? Nem me diga.

Caso alguém faça uso desse código, sugiro fortemente revisar a sincronização, pois não fiz testes extensivos e algo pode ter escapado.

Comment: Oi Luiz, muito obrigado, como sempre, pela excelente resposta. Se puder te encher o saco mais um pouco, meu principal problema é que a implementação de `filhosDiretos` assume que a árvore inteira está em memória, voltando ao problema inicial de `OutOfMemoryExceptions`. O que eu gostaria nesse algoritmo produtor / consumidor era ter algo mais *push*, em que o produtor empurra os nós já lidos. Caso o consumidor não possa persistir determinado nó pois um dos pais dele não foi persistido, essa escrita seria "atrasada" até o pai ter sido lido / escrito. Faz sentido?

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Hum... eu havia pensado na possibilidade que a implementação real fizesse algum tipo de query para obter os filhos e assim não incorreria em problemas de memória. Por outro lado, entendo pelo que você falou sobre empurrar os nós lidos, que a leitura dos nós não seria randômica, mas serial. É isso mesmo? A ideia seria guardar o nó e persistir assim que o pai for encontrado? Ou seria a ideia de buscar os nós pais sob demanda? Enfim, acho que a questão para mim é: qual é a interface de leitura/escrita usada para acessar os nós?

Comment: Eu tinha pensado em blocar a leitura conforme o código da questão (isso funcionou muito bem para a leitura e transformação). Isso significa que em um modelo producer / consumer só teríamos uma árvore parcial por bloco na hora da escrita. A ideia é leitura -> divisão por blocos -> n "threads" lendo e processando cada bloco -> blocking queue -> n " threads" recebendo e escrevendo os blocos. O ideal é persistir e tirar os nós da memória tão cedo quando possível. Porém não posso ficar fazendo muitas operações de escritas desnecessárias no banco.

Comment: Tanto "persistir assim que o pai for encontrado" quanto "buscar os nós pais sob demanda" (na verdade, esperar até que o bloco em que o pai foi persistido termine por algum tipo de notificação) são idéias válidas. A interface de leitura e escrita é assim mesmo como comentei. Só o que acessa o banco é o método `persisteElemento`, e somente os métodos `leArvore` e `leFilhos` acessam a interface externa (vou atualizar a pergunta), todo o resto é em memória.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Acho que ainda não entendi, dada a estrutura atual, como um nó filho poderia ser processado antes do nó pai. Se possível, insira um exemplo na pergunta onde isso ocorre.

Comment: Digamos que `elemento_1` esteja no `bloco 1` e `elemento_3` esteja no `bloco 2`. Caso a leitura da interface externa / transformação do `bloco 2` termine antes da do `bloco 1`, em uma estratégia *naive* onde sempre persistimos qualquer elemento o `elemento_3` seria persistido antes do `elemento_1` (o que não é possível). Por isso que hoje esperamos por toda a leitura / processamento e mantemos toda a árvore em memória antes de escrever no banco (o que, novamente, estou tentando evitar devido ao consumo de memória). A sutileza da coisa é que tanto memória quanto *writes* devem ser minimizados.