# Estrutura de tabela para árvore genealógico

Tags: estrutura-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados, convenções-de-nome

Como criar uma tabela com estrutura de árvore genealógico para um indivíduo utilizando uma nomenclatura concisa?

Exemplo:

1. Indivíduo

   - Pai

     - Pai (Avô paterno)

       - Pai (Bisavô paterno)
       - Mãe (Bisavó paterno)
     - Mãe (Avó paterno)

       - Pai (Bisavô paterno)
       - Mãe (Bisavó paterno)
   - Mãe

     - Pai (Avô materno)

       - Pai (Bisavô materno)
       - Mãe (Bisavó materno)
     - Mãe (Avó materno)

       - Pai (Bisavô materno)
       - Mãe (Bisavó materno)

Nome meu caso vai um pouco além do exemplo, chegando até o 5° de genealogia.

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2425/101

Comment: Isto só será para parentes diretos (pai e mãe, avo e avó)? Ou pra qualquer parente?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento no meu caso, apenas para parentes diretos, pai e mãe do pai e da mãe.

Comment: Uma ideia seria criar uma tabela apenas com 4 colunas `id`, `tipo`, `nome`, `idRelacionada`. Tipo seria resolvido na camada de aplicação e definiria se é avô ou avó (pode ser tynint de 0 e 1). `idRelacionada` seria a que pega a `id` do "filho(a)" em cascata. Vou tentar formular uma resposta, mas quero colocar um exemplo com mysql pra ficar mais claro :)

Answer (score 5):

Estruturas de árvore são recursivas por natureza e um possível modelo seria uma tabela em que cada pessoa possui um campo `id` e um campo `child_id` o qual aponta para a id do filho, dessa maneira você pode definir a árvore em profundidade ilimitada.

Veja abaixo um exemplo da ideia em MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    gender VARCHAR(6),
    child_id INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (child_id) REFERENCES person(id)
);

INSERT INTO person (id, name, gender, child_id) VALUES 
    (1, 'Indivíduo', 'male', NULL), 
        (2, 'Pai', 'male', 1),
            (3, 'Pai (Avô paterno)', 'male', 2), 
                (4, 'Pai (Bisavô paterno)', 'male', 3), 
                (5, 'Mãe (Bisavó paterno)', 'female', 3),
            (6, 'Mãe (Avó paterno)', 'female', 2), 
                (7, 'Pai (Bisavô paterno)', 'male', 6), 
                (8, 'Mãe (Bisavó paterno)', 'female', 6), 
        (9, 'Mãe', 'female', 1), 
            (10, 'Pai (Avô materno)', 'male', 9), 
                (11, 'Pai (Bisavô materno)', 'male', 10), 
                (12, 'Mãe (Bisavó materno)', 'female', 10), 
            (13, 'Mãe (Avó materno)', 'female', 9), 
                (14, 'Pai (Bisavô materno)', 'male', 13), 
                (15, 'Mãe (Bisavó materno)', 'female', 13)
    ;
```

Como já dito pelo Maniero no comentário da pergunta sua questão é intimamente relacionada com modelagem de árvores em bancos e uma discussão mais abrangente sobre tal pode ser encontrada [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2425/como-modelar-uma-estrutura-de-dados-em-%C3%A1rvore-usando-um-banco-de-dados-relaciona#answer-2426).

Comment: Perfeito! Eu só trocaria o `gender VARCHAR(6)` por `male BOOLEAN`.