# Banco de dados hierárquico(?) - SQLite/Android

Tags: android, sql, banco-de-dados, sqlite, tabela-banco-de-dados

Boa tarde, estou começando a estudar Android e pensei em fazer um aplicativo para já estudar juntamente banco de dados. Quero fazer uma "árvore genealógica", de forma que ao clicar no nome da pessoa (botão) apareceriam outros botões com o nome de seus filhos e assim respectivamente - talvez existam outras formas de exibir esses dados, estou aberta a sugestões.

Fiz um exemplo de uma agenda de contatos em Android (com botões para adicionar, excluir e listar os contatos), consegui entender o funcionamento, mas não sei como aplicar isso na minha ideia. Pesquisei e descobri a existência de bancos de dados hierárquicos, e acho que faria sentido utilizar essa ideia no aplicativo.

Porém, não estou encontrando conteúdo sobre isso, então se alguém pudesse me "dar uma luz" sobre o que pesquisar, ou alguma forma de programação que possibilite fazer o que preciso, ajudaria muito.

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Veja se isso resolve pra você: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2425/101

Comment: Olá. Bem vinda ao SOPT. Se não fez ainda, faça o [tour] e leia [ask]. Este site não é um fórum, e por isso a sua pergunta precisaria ser um pouco mais específica. Além de ler o link que já lhe foi sugerido, você pode [edit] a pergunta para focar em algum aspecto do seu problema (por exemplo, como relacionar pessoas em uma árvore genealógica em um banco de dados relacional).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O link postado no comentário é bem completo, porém, vou colocar aqui um exemplo de criação da tabela.

O modo mais simples seria fazer com que cada registro apontasse para seu pai (pois teoricamente, todo pai também é um filho), essa abordagem faz com cada pai possa ter N filhos, e cada Filho só poderá ter um Pai (o que no caso da árvore genealógica não é o caso,pois cada filho tem dois "pais"), desta forma, como temos um número conhecido e máximo de pais, podemos criar dois campos para eles:

```
CREATE TABLE pessoa(
id_pessoa INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
nome TEXT NOT NULL, 
sobrenome TEXT NOT NULL, 
id_pai INTEGER NOT NULL,
id_mae INTEGER NOT NULL, 
FOREIGN KEY(id_pai) REFERENCES pessoa(id_pessoa),
FOREIGN KEY(id_mae) REFERENCES pessoa(id_pessoa)
);
```

O lado ruim desta abordagem, é que o SQLite não suporta uma Query recursiva, ou seja, buscar um registro na tabela pessoa e fazer um "Join" com outro registro na mesma tabela, desta forma, você não conseguirá ter as informações do Pai na mesma query que o filho (a não ser que faça uma subquery, o que é um pouco mais complexo para quem está iniciando), então na prática, você teria que achar o filho, e depois fazer uma query com o `id_pai` que você encontrou no primeiro registro.

Comment: SQLite suporta consulta recursiva faz um bom tempo, veja [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/214625/resgatar-todos-os-n%c3%b3s-de-uma-%c3%a1rvore-do-banco-de-dados-sqlite/214626#214626) para maiores detalhes