# Dúvida com dados hierárquicos

Tags: php, mysql, dados-hierárquicos

Fala galera , tudo bem ?

Estou com um problema já tem uns dias , no sistema eu preciso controlar a exibição de alguns dados, eu tenho um cadastro de função , setor e empregado, ligados entre sim. Nessa regra de negocio, o Usuário pode montar seu setor e logo sua hierarquia de forma dinâmica , sendo assim , os Usuários só podem ver os dados deles e se eles forem responsareis por alguém, esse responsável pode ver os dados do seu subordinado e os dados do subordinado do seu subordinado e por ai vai.[image: imagem da tabela responsável , onde vejo a hierarquia de responsáveis]

Nessa tabela acima consigo saber quem é responsável por quem e assim consigo ter uma linha hierárquica.

Meu problema está em conseguir fazer essa escala , saber quem é responsável de quem e se essa pessoa que é subordinada é responsável por alguém tb , assim o primeiro responsável pode ver os dados do segundo responsável e ver os dados so subordinado desse responsavel. Alguém  sabe de um modo de fazer isso? E se assim é a melhor maneira de armazenar os responsáveis (Hierarquia)

OBS: na coluna `responsavel_titular` e `responsavel_subordinado` são os códigos do empregado.

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2425/101

Comment: Valeu demais , acho que vou conseguir implementar  algo que funcionará para mim. Obrigado!