# Duvida em Arvore Binario Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Considerando a arvore abaixo, eu tenho uma duvida.

```
            A
      B           c
   D    E       F   G
 H  I             J   K
```

Então, eu queria saber se tem ou existi alguma maneira de fazer um SELECT, onde eu traga todos os IDS que estão a esquerda de A. Porque conseguindo a esquerda o lado direito segue a mesma logica.

O programa cadastra pessoas. Então a pessoa A colocou 'B' e 'C' na sua rede. B a esquerda C a direita. Depois B colocou D e E, e por ai vai a arvore. Minha duvida é, tem como fazer um Select onde eu busco todos do lado esquerdo do A.

Agradeço a atenção desde já,
Eric Augusto.

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPT. Teria como [edit] seu post e acrescentar o código que esta utilizando, ou o que tentou fazer até o momento? Assim podemos analisar e sugerir uma alteração. Obrigado.

Comment: Veja se isso resolve: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2425/101

Comment: Então, posso postar pouco, ainda não consegui pensar em nada para fazer algo, mas tenho o codigo onde me baseio nas informações.]

Comment: Query ficou mt grande e não permite postar, seu eu postar pedaço por pedaço vai confundir

Comment: @bigown nenhum dos links me ajuda. Não é a msm coisa que eu preciso.

Comment: Então a pergunta não está clara. Se você melhorá-la e demonstrar onde está sua real dúvida dá pra reabrir.