# Qual é a maneira mais correta para armazenar arquivos

Tags: banco-de-dados, arquivo, estrutura-de-dados, sistema-de-arquivos

Sempre esbarro com esta dúvida quando tenho trabalhar com armazenamento de arquivos dentro de um software.

- É ideal que eu simplesemente grave eles em uma pasta qualquer e grave as informações no banco de dados, com um campo apontando para o caminho onde o arquivo se encontra?
- Ou é mais viavel que eu crie um campo "arquivo" e converta os bytes deste arquivo, centralizando assim todo o meu armazenamento no banco de dados?

No meu caso é mais especificamente arquivos '.mp3' e '.mp4' que são enviados para o usuário via streaming.

Como os arquivos podem se tornar bem grandes, acho que isso pode ser um problema na hora de armazenar diretamente no banco e por isso a primeira opção se torne mais viavél, mas em outros casos, existe algum caso que eu deva/possa armazenar no banco?

A pergunta [Como modelar uma estrutura de dados em árvore usando um banco de dados relacional?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2425/como-modelar-uma-estrutura-de-dados-em-%C3%A1rvore-usando-um-banco-de-dados-relaciona) cobre bem o assunto, mas para mim ainda não ficou muito claro essa questão do tamanho dos arquivos, e se eles de alguma forma podem afetar a performance do meu banco

Comment: A pergunta é diferente das outras duas... e por que eu não consigo responder?

Comment: Se abrir a resposta, eu transformo em uma:

A resposta é depende de cada caso, não há uma maneira correta e outra errada. Um estudo de um pessoal da Microsoft (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2006/04/tr-2006-45.pdf) chegou a conclusão que, no teste deles, até 1 MB compensava manter no banco, e acima disso no sistema de arquivos. como no seu caso são arquivos grandes, provavelmente terá performance melhor usando arquivos mesmo, e no BD armazenar apenas os meta dados, além do caminho do arquivo.

Comment: Algo parecido por exemplo que o Wordpress faz

Comment: @Dudaskank, a pergunta foi fechada e está sendo votada para ser reaberta. Enquanto está como [duplicada] não podem ser feitas alterações. Leia mais sobre: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates

Comment: @UzumakiArtanis eu posso votar rs?

Comment: Se você pode votar? Não. Somente pessoas com mais de 3.000 pontos de reputação e moderadores. @Dudaskank

Comment: Alguma dos atuais 3 links que tem lá em cima responde a sua dúvida? Mesmo que as perguntas ali não sejam exatamente iguais, as respostas resolvem seu problema?

Comment: Claramente o @bigown marcou corretamente, lendo a pergunta e vendo os post's correspondentes é possível chegar a uma conclusão para o "problema" e com isso resolve o problema dessa pergunta.

Comment: Sim, os links ajudaram a resolver o problema

Comment: @Everson Ele (bigown) tinha fechado apontando para o lugar errado, foi corrigir bem depois. Parte da confusão aqui foi por conta disso.