# Comparação: CTE vs CURSOR

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor, cte

Não sei se isto será uma questão que muitos se colocam, mas sempre a tive em mente quase desde sempre.

Normalmente, quando preciso entregar uma *script* corretiva a um cliente, utilizada para apenas ser executada uma única vez, utilizo um `CURSOR`, talvez por ser mais legível para quem não percebe muito de TSQL e por ser, de certa forma, mais simples de manter (a recursividade pode, muitas vezes, "complicar").

Mas em desenvolvimento tento, sempre que possível, utilizar `CTE` porque é "*o que se deve utilizar*", segundo os entendidos nesta matéria.

Por isso, questiono: **CTE ou CURSOR**?

Sei que CTE oferece, supostamente, mais *performance* em relação ao CURSOR, mas será isso o suficiente para a usarmos em detrimento da outra opção?

A questão da recursividade, como referi acima, pode muitas vezes complicar um processo simples, podendo inclusive tornar bastante difícil a manutenção de um *script* de vários níveis num cenário mais complexo.

Em `CTE` não nos é possível perceber ao certo o que é executado no intermédio, enquanto que com um `CURSOR` conseguimos colocar um `PRINT` ou `SELECT` com informação importante ou útil num processo de *debug* ou validação de resultados.

---

Resumindo, utilizar um `CURSOR` com recurso a temporárias (por exemplo), ou mesmo um ciclo `WHILE`, é assim tão pior que utilizar um CTE?

Claro que deve depender do cenário, mas sendo assim, onde devemos utilizar um e o outro?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Boas observações na pergunta. De fato, o cursor é a [forma mais imperativa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/127121/101), apesar de ainda ser colocado de [forma declarativa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81854/101) no código. O CTE é mais funcional. O motivo de achar mais legível é que programamos imperativo o tempo todo.

O CTE pode oferecer mais performance, mas isso não é automático e de fato por ser algo menos comum para muitas pessoas pode errar sem perceber e piorar. Mas ele pode fazer otimizações que você provavelmente não pensaria ou não teria condições de decidir de forma adequada de outra forma. Há casos que você pode prover melhor algoritmo.

Pelo que eu sei o SQL Server sempre jogará o dado do cursor em disco, e em se conformando pode ser que a CTE seja mais rápida em todas situações mais simples por ela se manter na memória, mas é uma falha de implementação, e que pode mudar um dia. Achei uma [comparação em um cenário específico](https://brianbeswick.com/2014/07/03/recursive-cte-vs-while-loop-performance-analysis/).

Lembrando que CTE costuma ser incompatível entre bancos de dados. Não que o cursor seja tão mais padronizado assim. Há casos que o SGDB não tem um ou outro e você fica sem escolha. Não é o caso do SQL Server, claro. E se optou por ele na pergunta imagino que essa questão não seja muito relevante.

Porque o CTE é uma abstração pode ser mais difícil entender o ocorre ali e como depurar o resultado, tem que brigar com a API em vez de brigar com o algoritmo. Para casos simples pode ser mais fácil, mas para casos complexos o CTE pode ser torturante. Com o CTE você abre mão do controle, o que pode ser bom ou não.

Experimente fazer sem CTE em [modelos em árvore](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2425/101). Assim como [abusar de recursão é ruim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21551/101), abusar de CTE pode ser ruim também. Mas assim como a [recursão é melhor em vários casos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107657/101), o CTE também.

De forma geral eu acho que deve usar o que se sinta mais confortável, mais legível. Performance deve ser medida, se perceber algo pior, mude, do jeito que se sentir mais confortável. Só não deixe o CTE de lado, para *queries* complexas pela pode tornar o código pelo menos mais expressivo.

Mas se você é um "programador" SQL, deveria optar pelo CTE. É a forma mais idiomática de fazer, tem mais cara de SQL. O mesmo que estou falando sobre CTE vale para o SQL. Se tiver uma forma, e alguns DBs possuem esta forma, de acessar sem usar o SQL você o faria de forma mais simples, e possivelmente legível para você, de forma imperativa.

Fazendo como *subquery* te deixa mais confortável? O CTE é só isso de forma mais "disfarçada".

Não existe uma resposta mágica que indique qual usar. Está tão errado dizer que só deve usar cursor quanto quem diz, e muita gente diz, que só deve usar CTE.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Acho que mais claro que isto é impossível ;)! Obrigado @Maniero.